# Count the number of same value pair of element in two list (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell

I want to count the number of pair of mutual elements in two lists without using any functions outside Prelude and Data.List. Each match only count once.

For example:

[A,B,A] and [C,A,C] return 1 (only 1 A).

[A,A,A] and [A,C,A] return 2 (2 A).

[A,B,C] and [C,A,A] return 2 (A and C).

Here is my attempt, I want to do it as short as possible but failed.

```
length filter (`elem` list1) list2
```

My code count will return 2 for [A,B,A] and [C,A,C] because it count all the matches in two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
import Data.List

countEm count []       l2 = count
countEm count (x : xs) l2 = if elem x l2
                             then countEm (count + 1) xs (delete x l2)
                             else countEm count xs l2
```

The `delete` function comes from `Data.List` and deletes just one element from the list.

Testing your examples:

```
> countEm 0 "ABA" "CAC"
1
> countEm 0 "AAA" "ACA"
2
> countEm 0 "ABC" "CAA"
2
```

It still could be more efficient by combining `elem` and `delete` into a function with those two responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Just sort and compute recursively.

```
getMatch :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
getMatch l r = getMatch' (sort l) (sort r)

getMatch' [] _ = 0
getMatch' _ [] = 0
getMatch' l@(a: as) r@(b: bs) | a < b = getMatch' as r
                              | a == b = getMatch' as bs + 1
                              | otherwise = getMatch' l bs
```

---

Test:

```
λ> getMatch "ABA" "CAC"
1
λ> getMatch "AAA" "ACA"
2
λ> getMatch "ABC" "CAA"
2
```